# WebSphere Portal 8 Remote Action

Tags: websphere-portal

I'm setting up a remote action, but I want to specify the authoring template.
How do I find the atid (or Authoring Template ID)?

Here's the example int he docs:
[plugin:RemoteAction action="new" type="com.ibm.workplace.wcm.api.Content" atid="ID1"]

Here's a link to the docs: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Web+Content+Manager+8+Product+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Using_remote_actions_wcm8&content=pdcontent

Name doesn't work, it's looking for an object ID (I think). I tried digging through a WCM data export and I tried following the HTTP requests when accessing authoring templates, but I just can't figure out how to get that ID.
Am I making this more complex than it is?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the specific elements I needed to get a UUID for and put them in a new library. Then I exported that library by itself and used grep to find references to the Authoring Template and Sie Area I needed.
That did the trick.
-p

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide the AT id in the remote action call, the URL will direct you to a page with a list of AT's. On that page, if you firebug/inspect element by clicking that specific AT, you'll see its ID in the HTML.